# C# out or range exception Chart

Tags: exception, charts, range, windows-forms-designer, updating

Hey guys I am trying to create an updating Line Chart in C# but I keep getting an out of range exception on `chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue.`
My Code goes like this :

```
        {    
    _valueList.Add(mspk);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();

    if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
        {

            while (chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue < chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum+5000)
            {

                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue - 5000;
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue + 5000;
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            }

        }
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(inst, _valueList[_valueList.Count - 1]);
    chart1.Invalidate();
    }
```

I am not very experienced in C# so I tried to adapt this code that uses random numbers over time. I had no problem switching from the random numbers to my input but I cant seem to figure out how can I replace time with my data

```
        private void AddData()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        //Insert a number into the list.
        _valueList.Add(_ran.Next(0, 100));


        chart1.ResetAutoValues();

        //Remove old datas from the chart.
        if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
        {
            while (chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue < now.AddSeconds(-5).ToOADate())
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = now.AddSeconds(5).ToOADate();
            }
        }

        //Insert a data into the chart.

        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(now.ToOADate(), _valueList[_valueList.Count - 1]);

        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: What chart type are you using?

Comment: It's the standard windowsforms Chart set as a Line chanrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that chart1.Series[0] exists before trying to access its properties.

```
    private void AddData()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    //Insert a number into the list.
    _valueList.Add(_ran.Next(0, 100));


    chart1.ResetAutoValues();

    if(chart1.Series.Count==0) // Check to make sure Series 0 exists
    {
        chart1.Series.Add("Series 1"); // If it doesn't exist then create it.
    }

    //Remove old datas from the chart.
    if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
    {
        while (chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue < now.AddSeconds(-5).ToOADate())
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = now.AddSeconds(5).ToOADate();
        }
    }

    //Insert a data into the chart.

    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(now.ToOADate(), _valueList[_valueList.Count - 1]);

    chart1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I feel so silly..  I tried to check whether there is  still points in the series before I used the remove command